# How to translate a python program (Qt translation files) on launchpad

Tags: python, qt, internationalization, pyqt4, launchpad

My python program uses `selt.tr("String bla bla")` to mark strings to be translated. I translate it using `pylupdate4 Translate.pro` and then edit the created  *.ts-fils with Qt-Lingust, then afterwards using `lrealese Translate.pro` to create the *.qm binaries that my PyQt4-program is loading.

Now I would like to know how I can make this on Launchpad. [Here](https://help.launchpad.net/Translations/YourProject) I only read about `mo`,`po`and `pot`-files, but what about my `ts`- and `qm`-files?

How can I translate my program on Launchpad?
I am not sure if QTranslator can read other binaries than qm-files.

Comment: cannot you just use Qt tools instead of launchpad?

Comment: @LaszloPapp well, afaik launchpad allows online translation by multiple people. Maybe he hosts the project on Launchpad too.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: that does not answer my question. ;-)

Comment: I implemented a tool to enable the users to translate it on their own. this is kind of new and can bring advantages, but still people need to know english to get to the menu, and if 100 people would translate it for the same language, it would be a waste of time, and also i would have to select the best translation

Answer (score 0):

Launchpad uses GNU gettext's file formats to import and and export translations:

- pot: a template that includes the English text that you want people to translate. What's this?
- po: translations for one language in a human-readable and editable form.
- mo: a compiled binary form of a .po file.

You can find out more about these file formats and using GNU gettext in the [Gettext manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/).

you can use [www.transifex.com](http://www.transifex.com) site ,this site use TS files